# Can we use outlook object model within Task factory?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, outlook-addin, outlook-2013, taskfactory

Hi we have a outlook addin. we have used task factory and background worker in code.  We have used WPF for our UI design. we see some issues reported for outlook crash and outlook disabling plugin.
what are the reasons that a plugin can go into disabled mode?

Comment: we have some workarounds to make the inactive or disbaled addin to be active. but how do we capture or identify what part of code is causing this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model should be used on the main thread only because Office applications uses the single threaded apartments. You are free to use a low-level API - Extended MAPI which can be used on secondary threads. Or any other wrapper around that API.

Comment: thank you ! are there any other reasons that could cause addin to disable mode or outlook crash ? we see many reporting this . but it is not reproducible in all machines. Another point here , we have some log files and json file in the users APPDATA/Roaming folder which our addin read and update. will this cause any issue related to outlook crash ?

Comment: Any exception in the code may cause your add-in trapped into the Disabled Items list.